# Error when running expo run on react native app

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, expo

When i run the app with expo start then after 5 seconds i got blank screen and this error

```
C:\Users\lp\apps\test\App>expo start
Starting project at C:\Users\lp\apps\test\App
Expo DevTools is running at http://localhost:19002
Opening DevTools in the browser... (press shift-d to disable)


Invalid regular expression: /(.*\\__fixtures__\\.*|node_modules[\\\]react[\\\]dist[\\\].*|website\\node_modules\\.*|heapCapture\\bundle\.js|.*\\__tests__\\.*)$/: Unterminated character class


Metro Bundler process exited with code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you thoroughly followed the [installation guide](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/get-started/installation/) ?